# Frequency functions give more occurrences than table has

Tags: excel

I have a column in excel with numbers between 0 to 0.66, and there are only 7952 entries. But the frequency functions shows way more entries (35732 to be exact).
What am I doing wrong?

```
: bins column has: 0 0.1 0.2 and so forth up to 0.7

=FREQUENCY(A1:A7952,B2:B9)
```

[image]

Please advice!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not entering formula correctly. Asusming your ***Data*** is in `A1:A7952` and ***Bins*** in `B2:B9`.  If you are displaying `FREQUENCY` in `Column C` then first select Cells `C2:C9` and then enter your formula

```
=FREQUENCY(A1:A7952,B2:B9)
```

as an array formula i.e. commit by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

See [this](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-frequency-function) for details.

Comment: @Tlalit - Did the solution help?